# jQuery localScroll and smoothScroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll, vertical-scrolling

jQuery localScroll and smoothScroll is not working at all on my site. Getting an error in my console saying that my function is not defined and that it's a type error.

Any suggestions on how to fix this and get the plug in working?

This is where I am calling localScroll and in return I get an error message in my console.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scrollTo/jquery.localScroll.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.localScroll();
    });
</script>
```

The error seems to be occurring here on this line bellow.

`$( document ).ready(function() {
            $.localScroll();
        });`

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions on using a different plugin / approach to smooth scrolling feel free to post and speak you're mind. All suggestions are good

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the scripts are included correctly? verified none is 404'd.
Else, open the console and see if there's any error message.

Comment: I'll send you what I have so far in a gh-pages link hold a sec

Comment: Here's my gh-pages link for you to dive into..http://kapena.github.io/pp_web/#services-pp

Comment: It's now using something else made by you, can't check